# JSONP call with server-side language as Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsonp, express

I've been trying to use JSONP to get a JSON object from a server via a client-side call (on a different port). However, because my server is implemented in javascript using Node.js and Express, I haven't been able to find much on JSONP with Javascript on the server as most sites I found used php for server-side code.

I believe the issue is with how I set up the url with respect to the callback, which I'm a bit fuzzy on cause it's new to me.

On the server:

```
//Setting up server stuff
var express = require('express'),
  app = express.createServer();
  app.use(express.logger());

//Making a connection to the mongoDB to get the data that I want to display in the JSON object
new Db('prism', 
   new Server("127.0.0.1", 27017, {auto_reconnect: false}), {}).open(function(err, db) {
   app.get('/getData', function(req, res) {
      console.log('JSONPCALLBACK CALLED WITH RETURNDATA PASSED IN; SERVER SIDE');
        if (typeof callback == 'function') {
        console.log('callback is defined');
        callback(returnData);
      }
      else {
        console.log('callback is not defined');
      }
   }
});
```

And on the client:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache : false });
$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:1337/getData&callback=?', function(rtndata) {
  console.log('SUCCESS');
  console.log(rtndata);
 });
```

embedded by the standard  tags.

But I get the error:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:1337/getData&callback=jQuery16108897686484269798_1311007334273?_=1311007334342 404 (Not Found)
```

The server is on port 1337 while the client is run through MAMP on localhost:8888. I'm not sure if its even a localhost related issue as I've been trying to get this setup running for a few days now.

I believe the issue has something to do with not writing this line, which is in php, into my server-side Javascript. Most of the JSONP examples I found had something like this. But I'm not sure.

```
if ($GET['callback'] != '') 
   $json = $GET['callback']."( $json )";
   return $json;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I apologize ahead of times for being super verbose.

Bests,
Cong

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two problems.  First is the 404.  Completely separate from getting the client-side jQuery code to work, you need to make sure that you can issue a regular browser request (i.e. paste in that URL) and get back what you expect.  I haven't used express, so it's hard for me to comment on why you'd be getting that, except to say that I don't see 1337 anywhere in your server-side code, just what appears to be the port number 27017.

The second problem is that you don't actually want to *execute* the callback on the server, just build the JSON response including the callback (string) prefixed to it.

So instead of this ...

```
  if (typeof callback == 'function') {
    console.log('callback is defined');
    callback(returnData);
  }
  else {
    console.log('callback is not defined');
  }
```

try this:

```
  if (callback) {
    console.log('callback is defined');
    res.write(callback + '(' + JSON.stringify(returnData) + ')');
  }
  else {
    console.log('callback is not defined');
  }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, but I do set the port as 1337; I only put in snippets of the code. I have the line:  app.listen(1337);. The port 27017 is used for connecting the mongoDB to get the data. I'm not exactly sure how it works, as I do have a separate terminal open running as a server for the mongoDB. As of the 404, when I go to the url: http://127.0.0.1:1337/getData/ , it does display the JSON obj, but along with the notification: Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json. I tried what you suggested, but I get the same issues. Sorry for the ugly format.

Answer (score 0):

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ there is an example that includes 2 '?' in the URL.

you only have one, so try

```
$.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:1337/getData?callback=?', function(rtndata) {
```

and see if that gets rid of your 404
then look @jimbojw suggestion for returning a proper jsonp formated responce.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var express = require("express");
var server = express.createServer();
server.enable("jsonp callback");
server.get("/foo", function(req, res) {
    // this is important - you must use Response.json()
    res.json("hello");
});
```

[jsonp with node.js express](http://vaboone.wordpress.com/2011/08/17/jsonp-with-node-js-express/)

Comment: in latest exp version use res.jsonp("hello");  it will give you json or jsonp based on you have appended ?callback=myfunc or no.